# Alpha Transparency Remove Background Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

Is there any way in Photoshop to remove a background color from an image, when some of the background is behind a transparent object.

So far, I've tried using masks and channels but have not made any progress. I want to make the background transparent, so that the bottle and 'ink' can be put onto a white background colour.

Many thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: See this:  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/how-can-i-remove-background-from-an-image-of-a-transparent-object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no automated way to set a color as transparent.

However, try `Select > Color Range` and choose "Yellows" from the drop down menu. Then create a layer mask based on that selection. You get some decent results.

It's not perfect. But it's then a matter of adjusting levels on the mask a bit and correcting for the color halos, just general refining.

Mask created after color range selection.... (no refinement)

[image: color range]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer - how would you suggest I refine it?

Comment: As I posted, a bit of a levels or curve adjustment on the mask to get those last bits of background. Then some Hue/Saturation adjustments to pull the yellow out... you basically have to experiment with a few options to see what works best. It's really not the greatest photo to work from.

Comment: How do you apply levels or curve adjustments to the mask?

Comment: @tobinjim click the mask thumbnail in the Layers Panel and choose Image > Adjustments > Levels (or Curves)

Comment: Well color me noob!  There's even a pop-up there for which channel you're working on! These clever folks.

Answer (score 3):

Just finished making a video on this topic which also shows how to get rid of the color cast afterwards -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6IhXVxBSQM

There is a way to set a color as transparent.. blend-if.

1. Convert to Lab
2. Layer > Layer Style > Blending Options
3. Blend if: B
4. Adjust the This Layer slider to get rid of yellows. Hold alt on a half of a handle to separate it and create a border radius for smooth transition.

[image]

The Curves 1 layer is then to get rid of the remaining color cast. I didn't know what color its supposed to be since I've got no reference point so I just went into the B channel and pulled the curve down slightly.