# How to create a graphic of a text with transparent background

Tags: transparency

I make custom cursors for Tumblr blogs and this was a request, but I can't seem to figure out **how to make all but the words transparent**; even the spaces in the loops need to be transparent:

[image: cursor request]

Comment: What have you tried? What software are you using? Is it already transparent in your graphic editing software and you just don't know how to save, or do you not know how to get rid of the white background to begin with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the background of an image transparent](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/making-the-background-of-an-image-transparent) or maybe http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/alpha-transparency-remove-background-photoshop

Answer (score 4):

You are not really giving us enough information, but I happen to know this font. You are not telling us what software you are using, so this will be very general.

To make it really easy:

- get the font
- write what you want
- save as png

that should get you the image without artefacts.
The font is called The king and queen, and you can find it on [dafont here.](http://www.dafont.com/the-king-queen-font.font?text=Love&psize=l)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Type/draw them on a new layer and delete your first layer.

Result:

[image]

Layers look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The quickest method is to use the white background to drive the transparency in a layer mask. This method requires no tracing and IMO is the easiest way to convert a white background to a transparent one.

Step by step instructions [can be found here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/replacing-whiteness-with-transparency-in-cs6/21686#21686).