# Extract text using photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image: makeup]

Hello,

I need to isolate the text on this makeup flask using PHOTOSHOP.

Lets say I need the white text on a separated layer, purple colored text on a separated layer and so on.. Using pen around every letter is not an option and not even magic wand on those little letters at the very bottom of the flask.

Comment: Why aren't they options?

Comment: So are you asking how to avoid doing work? Take a better picture.

Comment: Do you want to replace the label or are you actually looking to extract the graphics so you can use them somewhere else? Might be a better idea to just remake it. I don't know where you are planning to use it use it but there aren't many situations where it would be a good idea,unless the goal is to make it look terrible. It would be sort of like peeling off packing tape from cardboard and reusing it....

Comment: I need to learn some better and faster technique how to extract text from detailed background than with using pen or magic wand. 

It has nothing to do with some avoiding work :-D

Comment: If you want something to practise on, practise on something without that shine down the middle [google polarising filter], & without the shadowing caused by the glass thickness... & without the bubbly sticker... & the mould mark.

Comment: NOT the type of advices I was looking for. I need to extract it on this image. If it is not possible, thats OK, but dont post comments like "find a better pic".

Comment: THere is not really any good way to do this without a lot of hard breaking work. Though my advice is not tu try to use the selection tools paint the mask. Or if you must use polygon lasso for a garbage matte and then use select by color, then clean selection with a brush and refine edge. But its not really worth it IMHO, ts faster to remake the text design.

Comment: Ales - you're really not going to be able to use any kind of 'automation' to extract this, you're going to have to do it by hand, probably pen tool. The photo is badly lit & has confusing shadows against the product inside the bottle, which will make select by colour difficult. It's also badly out of focus, so you have no hard edges to work with. [There may also be some registration error/bleed in the printing, but that's hard to tell because of the focus issue.]

Comment: The time spent trying to use that blurry, distorted, badly lit, photograph, and ending up with a terrible result (as it would enevitably be), would be better spent recreating the artwork from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

This image has poor quality altough you have succeeded to get some lines straight and horizontal. Bad quality of the image makes this no hope case. All edges are far too coarse.

It has enough data for finding plausible substitute fonts for those texts which aren't custom drawings and redrawing manually those which are not font. Of course the redrawing is guessing due the low resolution, but many of us are well used to guess.

If you want extract all in straight away usable quality, you need a pro quality photo. What I mean:

- one line should fill nearly the whole image area
- absolutely flat light, zero shiny highlights and shadows
- image must be warped flat, now it's on a curved surface. Most of the characters are distorted
- all parts must be clipped properly because refraction and reflection in the glass or plastics clearly makes the edges not well defined. That's easy if you have high enough pixel resolution and sharp camera optics.

Backlight can be useful. Have several photos where camera is in a sturdy stand, only the light is changed.

Maybe the printed label is removable without breaking nor stretching it. A good photo would be much easier case if the label was placed on a flat surface.

I happened to have a free font which resembles the texts in your image. That font is Protestant (taken from FontZillion). It can be used in remaking the texts. Thinned versions must be made in vector editor such as Inkscape or Illustrator and you must straighten the texts for reference.

I retyped for fun some texts and tried to trace the logo. They of course do not fit exactly because the image isn't warped to flat. The logo is just maybe recognizable. Here are some of the fussings:

[image: ![enter image description here]

BTW. The grainy background of the label texts is the basic flat color + monochrome noise added. The background is stretched to larger size to make the grain visible.

Answer (score 1):

This particular image would be a challenge for anyones due to the poor lighting. The type at the top of your image is blown out. That will take manual painting to fill in the missing pixel data. In addition, the lighting is causing a shadow for *all* the type. That shadow will further necessitate manual painting on a mask to remove.

There's no easy answer for *that* particular image. It will merely take some hard work. You aren't going to find a 1, or even 10, click solution.

Using **channels** in Photoshop will generally *start* you on the right path, but it will still take a great deal of zoomed in, pixel-by-pixel, manual, painting to mask the type properly. This image would probably require at least 2 extractions - one for the violet elements and one for the white type. I doubt both could be effectively extracted at the same time.

Check out some questions/answers related to using Channels for extraction:

- [Alpha Transparency Remove Background Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/alpha-transparency-remove-background-photoshop)
- [How to remove a green/blue screen background using Photoshop CS5?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22422/how-to-remove-a-green-blue-screen-background-using-photoshop-cs5)
- [Removing the background from product photos](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82280/removing-the-background-from-product-photos)
- [How can I remove background from an image of a transparent object?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/how-can-i-remove-background-from-an-image-of-a-transparent-object)